# generate an auto prefix number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<select id="questionnaire_domain" class="form-control sync-option-text required" name="questionnaire_domain"><option value="ESS">Employee Satisfaction Survey</option><option value="CSS">Customer Satisfaction Survey</option><option value="VSS">Vendor Satisfaction Survey</option><option value="OQ">Orientation Quiz</option><option value="TQ">Training Quiz</option><option value="EI">Exit Interview</option><option value="EO">Employee Opinion</option></select>
<input class="form-control readonly" name="questionnaire_code" type="text" value="" id="questionnaire_code" readonly="">
```

I want to generate an auto  prefix number in the text field according to the selected drop down's option value.
E.g: If I select Exit Interview the auto generated prefix will be 'EI12345',here 'EI' comes from drop down value and '12345' is an auto sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate random number of any number of digits. Try this:

```
$("#questionnaire_domain").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000; // this will generate random number
    $("#questionnaire_code").val(val+""+random);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update `input` value when `onchange` of `select` by `nextElementSibling`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  up vote 0 down vote favorite
  <select id="questionnaire_domain" class="form-control sync-option-text required" name="questionnaire_domain" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value + this.nextElementSibling.value.match(/(\d+)/)[1];">
    <option value="ESS">Employee Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="CSS">Customer Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="VSS">Vendor Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="OQ">Orientation Quiz</option>
    <option value="TQ">Training Quiz</option>
    <option value="EI">Exit Interview</option>
    <option value="EO">Employee Opinion</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control readonly" name="questionnaire_code" type="text" value="11" id="questionnaire_code" readonly="">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the generation of the sequence number is based on the selectedindexchange of the dropdownlist? If so, consider the following snippets

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sequence_no = 1;
    $('#questionnaire_domain').change(function() {
        $("#questionnaire_code").val($(this).id + sequence_no);
        sequence_no += 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  up vote 0 down vote favorite
  <select id="questionnaire_domain" class="form-control sync-option-text required" name="questionnaire_domain" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value + this.nextElementSibling.value.match(/(\d+)/)[1];">
    <option value="ESS">Employee Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="CSS">Customer Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="VSS">Vendor Satisfaction Survey</option>
    <option value="OQ">Orientation Quiz</option>
    <option value="TQ">Training Quiz</option>
    <option value="EI">Exit Interview</option>
    <option value="EO">Employee Opinion</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control readonly" name="questionnaire_code" type="text" value="11" id="questionnaire_code" readonly="">
</body>
```